# @angular/core/@Inject() result with an error : NullInjectorError: No provider for

Tags: angular, angular-services

I found several posts on that topic but I'm obviously missing something.

My main goal is to use an Injectable that requires a parameter.

I found that the way to go is to use the decorator @Inject.

You can see my attempt here :https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-r5psb2?devToolsHeight=33&file=src%2Ftest-component.component.ts

And just if you can't load that page :

*FILE test-service.service.ts*

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TestService {
  constructor(@Inject('arg1') public arg1: string) {}
}
```

*FILE test-component.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from './test-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-component',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `<span>{{testService.arg1}}</span>`,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'arg1',
      useValue: 'value1',
    },
  ],
})
export class TestComponent {
  constructor(public testService: TestService) {}
}
```

*OUTPUT*

```
ERROR
Error: R3InjectorError(Environment Injector)[TestService -> arg1 -> arg1]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for arg1!
```

Answer (score 1):

You service is `providedIn:'root'`, so it means it defined in the root injector.

By doing

```
{
  provide: 'arg1',
  useValue: 'value1',
},
```

You only define the value in the `NodeInjector`, the injector that only belongs to the component.

To fix it, you should declare at the root of your app.

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {providers: [{ provide: 'arg1', useValue: 'value1']}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I think I understand the point but in that case, I don't get how it works in the exemple provided in that article : https://www.positronx.io/how-to-pass-parameters-to-angular-service-using-inject/
Also, does it mean that there is no way to pass attribute to Services at Component level ? So 2 Components can't use a variation of the same Service ? I guess the issue in that case is that the Service can't be a singleton anymore...